# The view is accepting mm/dd/yyyy but the model is dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to input the date from the view but the model is dd/mm/yyyy but the view only accepts mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: I downvoted because [It's hard to answer a programming question without code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/), also [Without a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example, it is hard to know what is wrong](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/)

Comment: I have a model where there

Comment: where there is public datetime creation date i want to input data into database from view but the view wants date format mm/dd/yyyy but the datetime default format is dd/mm/yyyy

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is apply the format you want in the html helper call, ie.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RegistrationDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")
```

You don't need to provide the date format in the model class.

Comment: where there is public datetime creation date i want to input data into database from view but the view wants date format mm/dd/yyyy but the datetime default format is dd/mm/yyyy